# Quickblox for chat application which works locally?

Tags: android, xmpp, quickblox, localserver

I have tried to make chat application which works by Firebase. And everything works well, but now I want to make chat application which works on local server.

How can I do this everything in my app except chatting is done. Please suggest me something which I can use in local server.

I found a tutorial which creates chat app using Quickbox. But I do not know will it work locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP server is compatible with android operating system.
In following link you can get an insight into its underlying factors.
[Here you can see its official documentation](https://xmpp.org/software/clients.html)

Comment: can I use xmpp locally

Comment: Yeah definetely you can, if this answered your question, please select the aforementioned answer of mine as the answer.

Comment: and which type of xmpp do you suggest to use? there are lots of to choose